# Executing a program located in another directory in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to execute a program that is located in another directory than location of python script which executes a program.
For example, if I my python script is located in /home/Desktop and my program 'Upgrade' is located in /home/bin, how would I execute it using python script? I tried it this way:

```
import subporcess
subprocess.call('cd /home/bin')
subprocess.call('./Upgrade')
```

But problem is that directory is not actually changed by using subprocess.call('cd /home/bin').

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you require the current working directory of the subprocess to be `/home/bin`? You don't state in the text, but your code suggest you try to do that (although it fails).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subprocess module supports setting current working directory for the subprocess, fx:

```
subprocess.call("./Upgrade", cwd="/home/bin")
```

If you don't care about the current working directory of your subprocess you could of course supply the fully qualified name of the executable:

```
subprocess.call("/home/bin/Upgrade")
```

You might also want to use the `subprocess.check_call` function (if you want to raise an exception if the subprocess does not return a zero return code).

The problem with your solution is that you start a subprocess in which you try to execute "cd /home/bin" and then start ANOTHER subprocess in which you try to execute "./Upgrade" - the current working directory of the later is not affected by the change of directory in the former.

Note that supplying shell to the `call` method has a few drawbacks (and advantages too). The drawback (or advantage) is that you'll get various shell expansions (wildcard and such). One disadvantage may be that the shell may interpret the command differently depending on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can change directory using os. The python script will remain in the folder it was created but will run processes based on the new directory.

```
import os

os.chdir()
os.chdir('filepath')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to join the two commands.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('cd /home/bin; ./Upgrade', shell=True)
```

This way you do not need to change the script run directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import os
os.system('python /home/bin/Upgrade')
```

If your program is not a `.py`, then just

```
os.system('/home/bin/Upgrade')
```

or

```
os.system('cd /home/bin|./Upgrade')
```

Comment: This does not change the current working directory of the subprocess as the OP might have wanted. It's not clear from his question that he wanted that, but the supplied code suggests that.

Comment: @skyking as question is unclear I used question title ('Executing a program located in another directory in Python')  to guess that this is the actual issue

Comment: @Andersson Yes, if that's what the OP wanted then your solution will probably do. I just wanted to make clear that this does not change the current working directory - just in case that's what the OP actually wanted.

Answer (score 0):

or you can have a look at the python relative import, depending on what it does and how is built your script in the Update dir