# Running Python a script from another directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

First, imagine the following file structure:

```
project-dir
|_ 
   package1
   |_ 
      __init__.py
      module1.py
      module2.py
```

And the following script contents:

module2.py:

```
def func_module2():
    print('func_module2 run')
```

module1.py:

```
from package1 import module2

module2.func_module2()
```

The following command creates an error when executed from the project-dir:

```
python package1/module1.py
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./package1/module1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package1 import module2
ImportError: No module named 'package1'
```

Why is this happening and how is it possible to run a Python script from another directory?

Python 3.5.2

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510944/executing-a-program-located-in-another-directory-in-python

Comment: Can you do `ls` to check if you are in the `project-dir` directory.

Comment: Yes I am indeed inside the project dir. You can tell from the error that module1.py is actually executed. The problem seems to be the import which is not handled properly for whatever reason.

Comment: You can also run it with this command: `python -m package1.module1`.

Comment: What is the python version?

Comment: Python version is 3.5.2

Comment: Accept the suggested edit that adds the proper tag please

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seem to be that `module1.py` and `module2.py` both lives in the same package. From `module1.py` you won't find `module2.py` in another package. Instead try:

```
import module2

module2.func_module()
```

Trying that I get:

```
> python package1/module1.py
func_module2 run
```

However if you want it to work as a package too (or using newer versions of python), you must istead use

```
from . import module2

module2.func_module()
```

but that will make `python package1/module1.py` not work since it will not be run as part of a package. Instead you can use

```
> python -m package1.module1
func_module2 run
```

Comment: `import module2` won't work. `from . import module2` will import the module properly. Running the script with this configuration generates another error: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: @user1211030 Have you tried? On my computer that works. However your suggestion `from . import module2` does **not** work as it will raise `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`. Note that by running `python package1/module1.py` it will not be considered to be in a package despite the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Please don't recommend implicit relative imports EVER. By the fault, if not using the explicit relative import syntax, the imports in next versions of Python are absolute, so using implicit relative imports is highly discouraged.

Comment: @skyking Yes I have tried. Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: `python -m package1.module1` works well, but I can't accept this answer if it includes suggesting `import module2`.

Comment: @user1211030 Why can't you accept that answer? It sounds then that your question is missing something important. Btw I'm not sure which version I used yesterday, but it was one 2.x and one 3.x (2.7 and 3.2 I'd guess).

Comment: @skyking `import module2` doesn't work under python 3.5.2 which is the version I'm refering to in the opening post

Comment: @user1211030 But the second option works I assume? Anyway the first option has other issues as well as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**module2** and **module1** are under the same namespace.
So it MUST be:

```
# module1.py
import module2

module2.func_module2()
```

`from package1 import module2` is valid only in the following context/namespace:

[image]

Exemple:

```
# test.py
from package1 import module2

module2.func_module2()
```

Comment: Please don't recommend implicit relative imports EVER. By the fault, if not using the explicit relative import syntax, the imports in next versions of Python are absolute, so using implicit relative imports is highly discouraged

Comment: It won't let me `import module2` in module1. Pycharm error is `No module named module2`. My file structure is exactly the one from your screenshot.

Comment: As I said, relative implicit imports (`import module2.py  # @ module1.py`) are deprecated. Use either explicit relative imports or absolute ones.

Comment: @Adirio Are you sure? I had not ever listen about that. Can you provide us an official source for further info?

Comment: Of course: Third bullet from PEP8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)